# Voltage divider formula?

Tags: voltage, resistors

Actually I am not able to understand how the author arrived at this equation using voltage divider formula ?

[image]

what I tried is , I combined the two 2R resistor connected to ground in series and wrote 4R then, it is in parallel with the single R resistor .

[image]

I am confused where I made the mistake, and also I request you to please  provide any general rule for this method .

Comment: The 2R resistors are not in series with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint. Using Thevenin's theorem, you can simplify the circuit like this: -

[image]

It should be a walk in the park for the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my method, which I think is valid.

First, let's label the resistors:
[image]

Then redraw the circuit so that it's easier to see what's going on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOelTz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, find the voltage at node A. From there it's easy to find Vin.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the voltage divider formula you can first calculate the voltage at the junction point which is:

Vx = \$ \frac{+V\cdot (3 || 2)}{3||2 + 2} \$ = \$+V\cdot\frac{3}{8}\$

Then apply the divider formula again to get Vin

2/3 * 3/8 = 1/4